# Shebangs in conda managed environments

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, shebang, hy

I am trying to write a program in Hy and run it per the instructions on the [Quickstart page](http://docs.hylang.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) in the documentation.

So I installed Hy using pip from the GitHub repo per the docs, then added executable permissions to the file with `chmod +x myfile.hy`.

To manage my Python environments, I use Anaconda's conda,  rather than virtualenv. Hence the shebang `#! /usr/bin/env hy` does not work for me, since the conda envs live in a different directory. From `conda info --envs` I see that their directories are

```
myenv     * /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv 
root        /home/myname/anaconda3
```

Now attempting to run the script with `#! /home/myname/.conda/envs/myenv hy` bash throws a `bad interpreter: Permission denied` error.

Where should shebangs point in this case?

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted?

Comment: I agree it's a bit harsh, you shouldn't be blamed to ask questions specially when you showed your investigation.

Comment: I propose closing this as a duplicate of [How do I activate a conda env in a subshell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914739/how-do-i-activate-a-conda-env-in-a-subshell). While this one is older (and IMHO more clearly stated), the answers on the other are more thorough and cover a range of alternatives.

Comment: I know that at the time I asked this question I didn't know what a subshell was -- I'd argue that my framing while less refined might have better SEO for absolute beginners! I'm not totally sure what the SO philosophy is around this though -- using the appropriate terminology is probably better for accessibility overall and so probably should trump beginner-accessibility

Comment: @Hugo I'm only suggesting you close it so the other answer is prominently linked at the top. Your answer would still be discoverable via search. I think it helps to have lots of different ways to state the question, but have a central location of common solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/env hy` will actually work with Conda.  You just need to say `source activate myenv` before running the script.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My env was activated, but I think I made assumptions without trying it. Appreciate it