# How do I activate a conda env in a subshell?

Tags: python, bash, conda, shebang, subshell

I've written a python program. And if I have a shebang like this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and I make the file executable with:

```
$ chmod 755 program.py
```

I can run the program like so:

```
$ ./program.py
```

Here is the issue. I use the [conda virtual environments](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#id1). When I run the program like above, the system creates a subshell that does not recognize the active environment:

```
(my_env) $ ./program.py
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

If I do it this way, however...

```
(my_env) $ python program.py
# blah blah... runs great
```

How do I specify the right environment for use in the subshell? Is it possible? I'd like to save my fingers the effort of typing the six character string that is `python`.

Another post, [Shebangs in conda managed environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131901/shebangs-in-conda-managed-environments), briefly touches on this but does not provide the right answer. Instead of activating the environment in the subshell, it just says, go ahead and ignore the shebang... just use the `$ python program.py` syntax.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## `conda run`

If you always plan to run the script from a shell session where `conda` is defined, then another alternative is let Conda load the env using the `conda run` command.  In this case, the shebang would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env conda run -n my_env python
```

The advantage here is that you don't need the env to be activated when you call `./program.py` and you don't have to hardcode the location of the interpreter.

**Note:** This command was added as a "preview" in Conda v4.6.0 (see [Release Notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.6.0)) to address [the issue of running a command inside an env](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2379).

Comment: This looks like the best answer. If someone else can verify it works I will make this the accepted answer. I don't really use conda environments anymore and I'd have to set up an environment and a dummy project. Would take more time than I care to invest in this right now.

Comment: @meh I can attest that it works for me on Mac OS X and Linux (shells configured with `conda init`). Not shebangs, but a Windows user confirmed that `conda.exe run python` worked for them [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58458618/570918).

Comment: Ok I'll give it to you.

Comment: This gives me `/usr/bin/env: conda run -n my_env python: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @0x5453 make sure `conda` is on your PATH (e.g., you have run `/path/to/miniconda3/condabin/conda init` for your shell). That's what "*run the script from a shell session where `conda` is defined*" means.

Comment: @merv `conda` is on my PATH.  Running `/usr/bin/env conda run -n my_env python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'` in a shell gives me a sane result.  It seems that my kernel is treating everything in my shebang after `/usr/bin/env` as a single argument.  ([This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399690/102168) question seems relevant.)

Comment: @0x5453 oh - never hit that before. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 29):

In your script, change...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

...to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

The python used by an activated conda environment is `${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/python` and not `/usr/bin/python`

Notice the difference?

```
(root) ~/condaexpts$ which python
/home/ubuntu/condaexpts/m3/bin/python

(root) ~/condaexpts$ /usr/bin/env python
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

(root) ~/condaexpts$ source deactivate

~/condaexpts$ which python
/usr/bin/python

~/condaexpts$ /usr/bin/env python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nehal, that there is the right answer. Does this have a name? What do I search for to find this in the documentation?

Comment: @meh It is a pretty common standard. Also go through this answer, which explains why we use this shebang. http://askubuntu.com/a/88314/95343

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: This depends on the parent conda environment already being activated, which was not my use case.

Comment: Can I specify only the environment name? E.g. the path I get like this work only on my computer (as in `/home/ubuntu/`) even if the same environment is installed on the other one (but under a different absolute path).

Answer (score 3):

You can also point directly to the environment with the shebang line so you need not depend on something setting up the parent environment prior to calling the script.

First determine your preferred python environment's path:

```
$ . activate mypython
$ which python
/home/username/anaconda/envs/mypython/bin/python      # for example
```

Then use it in a script:

```
#!/home/username/anaconda/envs/mypython/bin/python
import os,sys
print sys.executable
print os.__file__
```

The above script would give output like this:

```
/home/username/anaconda/envs/mypython/bin/python
/home/username/anaconda/envs/mypython/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
```

Having a non-generic command in the shebang makes the script less portable, but if you depend the specific packages in a particular virtual environment, this is what you want.

Comment: While I think this approach is usually fine, it should be noted that some packages use activation hooks to define the runtime context, and so using the interpreter directly without env activation would skip over this.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't run for me, however this did:

```
#!conda run -n your_conda_env_name python
```

This requires conda in $PATH, and was on Windows.

Comment: This didn't work for me. conda is in my $PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the `conda run` method mentioned above, and got the following error

```bash
/usr/bin/env: ‘conda run -n my_env python’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: use -[v]S to pass options in shebang lines
```

after a brief search i learned that here `env` treats `conda run -n my_env python` as a single long argument. and as the error message suggests, adding `-S` will solve this.

another problem is that `conda run` does not provide real-time output on the terminal by default, which might not be desired if you're just searching alternative to `!/usr/bin/env python`, adding `--live-stream` option will fix this.

so to put things together, the final shebang is like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S conda run --live-stream -n my_env python
```