# Running Conda commands in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, shell, conda

I can't run a Conda command using `exec` with my NodeJS app.

```
var conda_path = '~/miniconda3/bin/conda'

var cmd = conda_path + ' init bash & ' + conda_path + ' activate XYZ'
exec(command,
    function(error, stdout, stderr){

    }
);
```

I get the following error:

> /bin/sh: /Users/username/Desktop/repos/project/XYZ: is a directory
>
> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
>   use 'conda activate'. To initialize your shell, run
>
> ```
> $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
> ```
>
> Currently supported shells are:
>     - bash
>     - fish
>     - tcsh
>     - xonsh
>     - zsh
>     - powershell
>
> See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
>
> IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running
>   'conda init'.

I can find no related information online regarding running conda commands from NodeJS app.

How can I make this work?

Comment: If you need to run a command or script in a Conda environment, consider using `conda run` [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58458618/570918), which circumvents having to manually activate. If you are trying to manipulate Conda envs programmatically, then I suppose that's a different story.

Comment: I might try it out. I figured out a working solution tho.

Comment: Now that I see your command, yes you should definitely switch to `conda run`. Also, `conda init` is really only meant to be run once and has a user-level side-effect of editing the shell initialization script - fortunately it's idempotent, but it's a waste here. You should actually look at the code it generates to see how to initialize a shell session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t seems to work using the `&` character to run multiple commands.

I also needed to specify the path to `conda.sh` which resides inside `/users/username/miniconda??/etc/profile.d/`.

This file can be copied to any location, e.g your NodeJS app's root folder.

Here's the working code:

**Windows 10**

```
var commands = [
        'C:\\anaconda\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\anaconda',
        'conda activate XYZ_v0_1_env',
        'XYZ arg1  <some_file_input> arg2 arg3 arg4 <some_file_output>',
    ]

exec(commands.join(' & '),
    function(error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log(error)
        console.log(stdout)
        console.log(stderr)
    }
);
```

**OSX**

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

var conda_path = __dirname + '/conda.sh'

var commands = [
        conda_path,
        conda_path + ' init',
        conda_path + ' activate XYZ_v0_1_env',
        'XYZ arg1  <some_file_input> arg2 arg3 arg4 <some_file_output>',
    ]

exec(commands.join(' & '),
    function(error, stdout, stderr){
        console.log(error)
        console.log(stdout)
        console.log(stderr)
    }
);
```

---

**EDIT: Using `spawn` instead of `exec` to read the live output of the process, i.e to generate live progress:**

```
var commands = [
        'C:\\anaconda\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\anaconda',
        'conda activate XYZ_v0_1_env',
        'XYZ arg1  <some_file_input> arg2 arg3 arg4 <some_file_output>',
    ]

var spawn_ = spawn(commands.join('&'), { shell: true });

spawn_.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    //do something
});

spawn_.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    //do something
});

spawn_.on('exit', function (code) {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 3):

### `conda run`

Conda provides the `conda run` command for executing programs or running scripts inside an environment without having to manually activate it. In your case, you only need one command then, e.g.,

```
var conda_exec = "C:\\anaconda\\Scripts\\conda.exe"
var env_name = "XYZ"
var sub_cmd = "XYZ arg1 <some_file_input> arg2 arg3 arg4 <some_file_output>"

var command = [conda_exec, 'run', '-n', env_name, sub_cmd].join(" ")

...
```

Be aware that `conda run` currently does not return I/O results until the very end. This means you won't be able to measure progress of the executing command, and also that you shouldn't use this if you expect a large return (i.e., won't fit in memory).

---

**Suggestion**: Consider naming the env `XYZ_env` or even include versioning (e.g., `XYZ_v0_1_env`), so you distinguish between `XYZ` the env and `XYZ` the program.

Comment: Great answer. Although I will unfortunately mark my own answer as correct due to it's versatility. Thank you for the env naming advice.