# How to change default python environment when running a .py file in windows batch file

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-10

I am trying to run a python script via a batch file (eventually to be run in task scheduler). When I run the file in PyCharm it works correctly. However, when I try to run it with the batch file it seems to be using a different version of Python (I am getting a numpy import error). I am using Windows 10 and the file is inside of an Anaconda project. I have checked that the Anaconda version of Python is first in line in the PATH. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Find out the python environment associated with Pycharm.  Take look here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: I did this and linked PyCharm to the Anaconda version. The file runs correctly through PyCharm but not when I run the batch file.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment

Comment: Sort of related (note how to execute an arbitrary Python script within a specific environment): https://stackoverflow.com/a/58458618/570918

Answer (score 2):

Your script is probably running in a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). In practice that means that some environment variables change, so `python` will run a specific binary, and packages will be looked for at some specific place. But well, you know that, as you mention the PATH thing.

To find out the *virtual environment* you can get and print your environment variables from your script. When run from PyCharm you should see the change in the PATH you mention, but also some other PY-related variables pointing inside your Anaconda directories.

Still better, you might be able to find a `.../scripts/activate.bat` or `.../bin/activate` (Windows or Linux, respectively). Calling that at the beginning of your script should do the trick.