# How to set the conda environment to use inside a python script

Tags: python, conda

I need to run in the same environment a script `workflow.py` that use python 2.7 and another script  `stepA.py` that use python 3.7.

Let suppose that `stepA.py` is called from `workflow.py`, one possibility is to setup two conda env, one with python2.7 and another with python3.7, run `workflow.py` in the py2env and write something like

`subprocess.run('bash -c "source activate py3env; stepA.py"', shell=True)`

in `workflow.py` to launch `stepA.py`.

I do not like this solution, instead I would like to modify the first row `workflow.py` and `stepA.py` by indicating the python version to be used, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

instead of simply

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

this second solution seems to me more atomic and dry.

I tried something like

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.7.12
$ conda create -n py3env python=3.8
[...]
$ conda env list
# conda environments:
base                  *  /sto1/ref/miniconda2
py3env                   /sto1/ref/miniconda2/envs/py3env
$ cat ./test.py
#!/usr/bin/env conda run -n py3env python
import os,sys
print sys.executable
print os.__file__
$ ./test.py
/usr/bin/env: conda run -n pheatmap_1 python: No such file or directory
```

So the *conda run* solution seem not working.

What is the proper way to set the environment for inside the script (in the `#!` row or with other strategies)?

Comment: Duplicate question: [How do I activate a conda env in a subshell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914739/how-do-i-activate-a-conda-env-in-a-subshell). In your case, you are missing the `-n` flag to name the env in the `conda run`.

Comment: Hi @merv, I added the -n but still do not work, see in the edited question the error it gives to me.

Comment: It looks like it's not finding Conda? Is the shell you are running the script from set up to use Conda? I.e., you've run `conda init` and `conda` is defined? Please add how you launch your script. E.g., `./workflow.py`?

Comment: @merv I edited the question and added a complete test.

Comment: I'll note that I ran into "conda run" not working when I installed the latest conda on a new system roughly when this question was posted.  Reading the docs, it looked like they disabled that ability.  Dialing back the conda version let me run "conda run" again, which is critical for my workflow because I have aspects of different codes that must run together, but interfere with each other so have to be run in different conda environments.

Answer (score 2):

You should be giving the full path to your python which should be given as executable

for eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /user/intelpython/latest/envs/py3env/bin/python
code
```

In this `/user/intelpython/latest/envs/py3env/bin/python`(My full path to a particular python) can be either python3 or 2
To get the absoulte path activate an environment and use `which python` command

Comment: Thank you for the int, but hardcoding  the path will make this solution not portable. I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: Okk... Makes sense

Comment: Is python2.7 the right name of your python 2  executable and is it added to the path

Comment: You can check with command if  "which python2.7" return it's path