# dataframe issues in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have found similar issues resolved with NA omit, however I can't seem to have any luck with it though.
could anyone advise me how why pathF might have zero rows? I'm new to R

```
library(tidyverse)

data_path <- paste (setwd ("Data"))
SamplesF <- list.files(path = data_path, pattern = "*.R1.fastq.gz", all.files = FALSE,
       full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
       ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)

TabF <- as.data.frame(SamplesF)

PathF <- data.frame(lapply(TabF, function(TabF) {gsub("Data/", "$PWD/N/", TabF)}))
PathF <- data.frame(lapply(PathF, function(PathF) {gsub("fastq.gz", "fastq.gip", PathF)}))

names(PathF)[names(PathF)=="SamplesF"] <- "absolute-filepath" 

PathF['direction']='forward'

PathF['sample-id']= SamplesF
```

Heres the error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "direction", value = "forward") : 
replacement has 1 row, data has 0
Calls: [<- -> [<-.data.frame
Execution halted
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example and at a minimum note the line on which this error occurs.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52496914/tidyverse-conflicts-with-automatic-manifest-maker?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi lmo I totally agree this needs to be more concise but at this moment in time, I don't know which line the error occurred on but I will absolutely edit this down as soon as I can.

Comment: ANG, you are correct! That was me last week, I've been working on this every day and still cant work out what is going on, if you read that thread you'll see it was never resolved

Comment: What I'd do is to run each line separately and see where it fails. You could do this in terminal or in RGUI (for windows) by opening R and copy/pasting each line. It is easier to use Rstudio and select blocks of code and use `ctrl+Enter` to execute it.

Comment: The error is thrown by this line `PathF['direction']='forward'`. You'll have to investigate why `PathF` has zero rows at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In the function `list.files` the argument `pattern` is expecting a regex expression (type `?regex` into R), it looks like you are using a command line type expression where `*` would be a wildcard.

It is likely there are no matches to your string when interpreted as regex. So you are working with length(0) data from the start.

Instead try: the pattern as `".R1.fastq.gz$"`

```
SamplesF <- list.files(path = data_path, pattern = ".R1.fastq.gz$", all.files = FALSE,
       full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
       ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
```

and see how that goes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm afraid that didn't change the output

Comment: Can you check what is in `SamplesF`? Also you need to check that where you are looking the files is where your think. `data_path <- paste (setwd ("Data"))` sets `data_path` to the folderpath prior to changing the working directory. so it is not searching the "Data" folder, but is searching the parent folder.

Comment: There is a subdirectory `Data` to the working directory, it contains any number of `fastq.gz` files

Comment: in the `list.files` function try `path = ""`, this will mean it looks in the working directory, which in the previous line you have changed to `Data`

Comment: I got this  error when i changed to `path = ""`
`Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "direction", value = "forward") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
Calls: [<- -> [<-.data.frame
Execution halted`

Comment: The problem is still caused by `list.files` not finding any files that match the string. I cannot say why it does not find them since I do not know the contents of your drives. I would suggest you to try `pattern = ""` and see it you can make any sense of what it returns, to make sure you are searching in the right place.

Comment: It dosn't have a problem finding the files, the manifest.csv it produces has got the details of the files in it, the issue is that it keeps printing the filepath before the sample ID.
But just to clarify, I have got several files ending in the string `R1.fastq.gz` in the subdirectory `Data`